# The Möbius function is the sum of the primitive $n$th roots of unity.

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, mobius-function

Did you know that the Möbius function $\mu$ is the sum of the primitive nth roots of unity? I want to know about meaning of this.

This statement is expressed as,
 $$\mu(n) = \sum_{\substack{k=1 \\ (k,n)=1}}^n \exp\left(\frac{2\pi ik}{n}\right).$$

Comment: Same question in disguise: [Coefficient of $n$th cyclotomic polynomial equals $-\mu(n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/737892).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is true that the Möbius function $\mu(n)$ is the sum of the primitive $n$th roots of unity.

Perhaps the easiest way to see this is to write
$$ \sum_{(k, n) = 1} e^{2\pi i k / n} = \sum_{k = 1}^n \sum_{d \mid (k,n)} \mu(d) e^{2 \pi i k / n} = \sum_{d \mid n} \mu(d) \sum_{\ell = 1}^{n/d} e^{2 \pi i d \ell / n}.$$
We get the first equality by using the property
$$ \sum_{d \mid n} \mu(d) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if } n = 1 \\ 0 & \text{ else } \end{cases},$$
and we get the second equality by swapping the orders of summation. In the final expression, the inner summation is a sum of all the $(n/d)$th roots of unity, and thus is zero except in the case when it's trivial, which occurs when $d = n$. So the only surviving term is $\mu(n)$, and we've shown
$$ \sum_{(k,n) = 1} e^{2 \pi i k / n} = \mu(n),$$
as you wanted to show. $\diamondsuit$

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you interchange the sums in the second equality? I don't see why first we sum over de greatest common divisors on the LHS and then over de divisors in the RHS.

Answer (score 5):

A slightly different approach goes like this: introduce

$$\alpha(n) = \sum_{k=1,\; (k,n)=1}^n \exp(2\pi i k/n).$$

Then we have

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \exp(2\pi i k/n) = [[n=1]]
= \sum_{d|n} \sum_{(k,n)=d} \exp(2\pi i k/n)
\\ = \sum_{d|n} \sum_{(k/d,n/d)=1} \exp(2\pi i (k/d)/(n/d))
= \sum_{d|n} \alpha(n/d).$$

Now from the relation

$$\sum_{d|n} \alpha(n/d) = [[n=1]]$$

we may  conclude that $\alpha(n) =  \mu(n)$ by inspection.

If this is not sufficient use Mobius inversion to get

$$\alpha(n) = \sum_{d|n} \mu(d) [[n/d=1]]
= \mu(n).$$

Comment: What do you mean by $[[n=1]]$?

Comment: This is an [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).