# Showing $\mu(n) = \sum_{k} e^{2\pi \frac{k}{n} i}$ using cosine explanation

Tags: number-theory, analysis, mobius-function

Who closed this question? the similar one is actually different, if you see the answer.

The mobius function $ \mu (n)$, is a function with property:

- $$\mu(1) = 1$$
- $$\mu(n) = 0$$ if $n$ is of the form $p^{2} \times (...)$
- $$\mu(n) = (-1)^{j}$$
  if $n$ is exactly product of $j$ distinct primes

For example: $\mu(16) = 0$, $\mu(15)=1$, $\mu(14)=1$, $\mu(13)=-1$.

My question is, how to show that it can be written using the complex form:

$$ \mu(n) = \sum_{k} e^{2\pi \frac{k}{n} i}$$, for $1 \le k \le n$ such that $gcd(k,n)=1$

---

**Attempt:**

For the complex part, it will be $\sin \left(2 \pi \frac{k}{n} \right)$, and this will be zero because if $k$ is such that $gcd(k,n)=1$ then we must also have $gcd(n-k,n)=1$, and both $\sin(2 \pi k/n)$ and $\sin((n-k)2\pi/n)$ will cancel each other.

But how to see the relation of the cosine?

Comment: Hint: What's the relationship between $\cos(k\frac{2\pi}{n})$ and $\cos((n-k)\frac{2\pi}{n})$

Comment: @Moko19 , they are the same. But then what?

Comment: Who closed this question? the similar one is actaully different, if you see the answer

Comment: Actually the present question is a duplicate of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1892410).