# Prove the sum of nth complex primitve roots of unity is $\mu(n)$

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing, roots-of-unity, mobius-function

I am trying to prove the following statement,

Let ω be a complex nth root of unity. We say that ω
is a primitive nth root if $\omega^m\neq1$ for any positive $m < n$. Prove that for all
$n\in\mathbb{N}$, the sum of the primitive complex nth roots of unity is $\mu(n)$.

I know this somehow involves the Mobius inversion formula but aside from this I do not know how to progress. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @AnneBauval I'm very new to Number Theory, thank you for your response but I am unfamiliar with this concept and do not seem to understand it even after reading it. Is it ok if you could explain the relation in simpler terms?

Comment: Hi @Mathsbot69 I wrote a much simpler answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/737892/coefficient-of-nth-cyclotomic-polynomial-equals-mun/4599479#4599479).