# Compute a trigonometric sum with indices relatively prime to $n$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, modular-arithmetic

The question is : how can I compute the sum :
$$S(n)=\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n \cos\left(\frac{2k\pi}{n}\right) $$
where $\gcd(k,n)=1$

Where $n$ is prime, $S(n)=-1$ because $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n \cos\left(\frac{2k\pi}{n}\right) = 0$

By calculating the first values of the sequence (for $1 \leq n \leq 20$), we obtain :
$$1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 1, -1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, -1, 1, 1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0$$
The closest sequence in OEIS is : https://oeis.org/A355690

It seems that if :
$$n= \prod_{k=1}^{r}p_k^{a_k} \qquad i \not =j \Rightarrow p_i\not = p_j$$
We have :
$S(n) = 0$ if $\exists 1\leq k \leq r, \; \alpha_k> 1$ and $S(n)= (-1)^r$ otherwise.

I suspect it is related to the cyclotomic polynomials.
How can it be proved?

Comment: it's the real part of the sum of all primitive n-roots of unity. What is it in terms of cyclotomic polynomials?

Comment: [A008683](https://oeis.org/A008683)

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/737892/coefficient-of-nth-cyclotomic-polynomial-equals-mun

Comment: Thanks, Anne Beauval.
It is effectively as you stated related to the Mobius function.